# About Polarization Density Matrix of Electron

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

This is my understand of polarization Density Matrix of Electron. Can you let me know if there is anything incorrect? Thanks a lot!

1. In rest frame, Polarization Density Matrix is only needed for ensemble of electron. If there is only one single electron, its spin is well defined and it is "fully" polarized (so always in pure state)?
2. In moving frame, spin vector doesn't conserve. So even for one electron, we need polarization density matrix to describe its state (pure, partially polarized or unpolarized).

Probably I am wrong. But I don't understand why for single electron, one still talks about polarization density matrix (or not? maybe I misunderstood the intention of the book). Thanks a lot!

Comment: 1. No. In principle a single electron, at rest (zero momentum) or not (finite momentum), can be entangled with another system, in which case its state is mixed. But one still needs an ensemble of identically prepared electrons to characterize it.  Whether you prefer to think about its spin state as just a mixed state described by a density matrix, or one of two orthogonal spin eigenstates of the density matrix occurring with a certain probability, is a somewhat subtle matter of interpretation. But it is not important as long as the dynamics is linear.

Comment: 2. No again. "Electron in moving frame" means "electron with non-zero momentum", and pure states of finite momentum _and_ well-defined spin are not a problem. What you may have in mind is that a state of well-defined spin does not remain a state of well-defined spin under a Lorentz boost. This is because Lorentz boosts mix momentum and spin degrees of freedom due to Wigner rotation. For a good intro see for instance http://xxx.lanl.gov/abs/quant-ph/0508049.

Comment: Thanks! If a single electron is not entangled with others, does it mean it has definite polarization? After more thought, maybe it is not necessary for an isolated electron to have definite polarization? Spin is an internal property but it doesn't mandate the electron to be polarized? Am I right? The reason I have such thought is that now I am reading neutrino. It is massless and it is completely polarized (e.g. anti-parallel to momentum). Being massless mandates it to be polarized. Then for massive electron, doesn't look like it has to be?

Comment: It's more like polarization vs. pure or mixed state. A single electron in a pure state is always 100% polarized along some direction. That is, you can always find a direction $\vec n$ and a corresponding spin operator $\sigma_{\vec n}$ such that the electron state is one of its eigenvalues and $\langle \Delta \sigma_{\vec n}\rangle = 0$. But in a mixed state there always is some finite uncertainty in polarization along any direction, and $\langle \Delta \sigma_{\vec n}\rangle \neq 0$ for any $\vec n$.

Comment: As for how this relates to entanglement, the reduced state of an entangled electron is mixed, but not all mixed states are entangled. For instance if two electrons are in a separable mixed state, each is in a reduced mixed state, but any correlations between them are classical and there is no entanglement. Note that although this kind of state is more readily realized as an ensemble, in principle nothing prevents us to prepare it on two electrons only. But for any mixed state there is some uncertainty in polarization.

Comment: Thank you! For a single electron not entangled with the others and without external field, for the spatial part of the wavefunction, is it right that an example of pure state is exp(ikr) and a mixed state is e.g. a wave packet? For the spin part of the wavefunction, a pure state is having the spin pointing in a particular direction (polarized), for a mixed state, it has both pointing up and pointing components. However, for the "mixed state" of spin part, isn't that one can always do transformation so it is pointing to a particular direction (so it is actually a pure state)?

Comment: Plane waves are of corse pure states, and so are spherical waves. But a wave packet may be either a pure state, or a mixed state. In fact a wavepacket as a (coherent) superposition of plane waves is a common example of pure state. Otoh a statistical mixture of plane waves is also a "wave packet" and is obviously a mixed state.

Comment: For spin, a pure state is indeed always an eigenstate of a spin projection along _some_ direction. Which means you can always rotate your z-axis along that direction and have the state as an "up" or "down" eigenstate of $\sigma_z$. But, this is **not** true for mixed spin states. In fact this is how you can tell apart mixed spin states: a state is mixed if there exists no direction along which it is clearly an "up" or "down" state.